# CkEditor 5 custom build SourceEditing does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ckeditor

hey I'm ATM customizing ckeditor for a client and SourceEditing does not work even there is no error in console the custom build is from ckeditor online builder

here is the code and thanks in advance

pastebin.com/JpK0eSXs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.